# What do I need to know to write a dcm file explorer?

Tags: c#, dicom

I'm recently asked to write a simple dcm file explorer (read the .dcm file and display with some zoom in/out functions). I have some .net experience(WPF, WinForm etc) but know little about the dicom. Are there simple demos for learning? Or what I should know to complete this work? Any suggestions or hints will help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start you need knowledge about DICOM format, that can be easilly found on internet.
Like a start can have a lok on[DICOM Image Viewer](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36014/DICOM-Image-Viewer) example on CodeProject.

The rest is matter of patience and time, it's not so complicated.

Answer (score 2):

OpenSource library for C#: [EvilDicom](http://evildicom.rexcardan.com/)

Library: [GDCM](http://gdcm.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Main_Page)

And other: [Dicom-CS](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dicom-cs/)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you take a look at [fo-dicom](https://github.com/rcd/fo-dicom). In the *Examples* folder there is a Windows Forms application *DICOM Dump* that provides the functionality you request. It should serve as a good starting point for your task.

Answer (score 0):

The world of dicom is beautiful and well defined in a set of solid specs documents. However, if you are only interested in creating a simple viewer, the very steep learning curve might be too much for your needs.

Unless you're planning a full career centered around dicom (or at least a very big project), it makes more sense to use a ready library or toolkit. A quick search of CodeProject for DICOM SDKs brought up this example:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/453732/Developing-DICOM-Viewers-for-Real-World-Applicatio

Comment: Thanks,Mesut, I decide to use a open source lib, I'll search it later

Answer (score 0):

A good starting point could be the [ClearCanvas](http://www.clearcanvas.ca/dnn/) library, which is available as open source [here](https://github.com/ClearCanvas). 
In addition, to get a good idea about the DICOM standard you could read up on some parts of the standard [here](http://medical.nema.org/standard.html) to get an idea about what kind of data you're dealing with.

Answer (score 0):

I've used Fo-Dicom and is very good, the images have a "Scale" property that makes easy the zoomIn/ZoomOut feature..